# Will my app be rejected if I will remove code of in app from my app?

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-app purchase(non-renewing subscription) in previous version of my app and it's got approved. I have now integrated paypal for purchase purpose and removed code for in-app on pay button click. So i have now confusion about my app approval. Will it cause any problem in my new version approval if they will not found in-app anywhere in my app?

Comment: What type of purchases are you allowing to do in your app with PayPal..? Are they digital within the app..?

Comment: @RoOmin: Single paypal payment i have implemented to remove ad and give extra features to user.

Comment: if your application sells some physical goods (clothes, tickets etc...) in your app, you can use Apple-Pay (iOS8+), PayPal or other payment libraries for it, otherwise the In-App purchase is your friend.

Comment: It might not get you rejected, but you also need to continue giving users a way to 'Restore Purchases' even if you remove IAP's.

Comment: What will happen if I select in-app purchase to off in capabilities from application target?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is going to be rejected anyway by apple because you are integrating PayPal to buy digital goods in your app i.e allowing user to buy extra functionality of your app or allowing user to pay to remove ads from your app.

YOU CANT DO THAT. YOU MUST INTEGRATE IN-APP PURCHASE TO DO THAT.

You can integrate PayPal only to allow trading of physical goods.

Read this:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies